# Prevent repainting of window in C++

Tags: c++, windows, gdi+, hook, repaint

I am writing a global hook DLL that needs to do some drawing using GDI+ on a window in response to an event. My problem is that the window that is being drawn keeps repainting itself, so what I draw gets erased before I want it to. Is there any way I can prevent the window from painting anything for as long as I need to?

My hook currently is a `WH_CALLWNDPROC` hook. The drawing is done using GDI+ in response to the message `WM_SIZING`. I drawing using GDI+ onto the window's `DC` (i.e. `GetWindowDC`). What I am drawing is drawn correctly, but gets erased almost instantly as the window client area gets repainted. The program that created the window I am drawing on is Notepad. As the cursor blinks, what I have drawn gets erased.

Does anyone know of a way I can temporarily suspend painting of the window?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest putting your graphics in a layered window overlapping the target window. That seems to be the cleanest way. After all, at some level of conception, this is the purpose of the window manager :)

Comment: I'm not creating my own window. I program is intended to draw something on any normal window as it is being resized, not just Notepad.

Comment: why can't you create a window? what does Notepad have to do with this?

Comment: You said to put my text into another window and overlap that window with mine. I don't think I mentioned drawing text, but I mentioned Notepad, so I thought you assumed that I wanted to draw some text onto a Notepad window.

Creating a window for the purpose I require seems to me a little too much trouble for something simple like this, but I will consider it.

Comment: edited my answer. i don't know where i got the idea you were writing text :P sorry about that

Comment: @AniDev This is the cleanest and simplest solution; You will find that making your idea to have your target window not overwriting what you drew into it working is going to be a lot harder.

Comment: @Fozi, maybe `HWND_TOPMOST` on the transparent window can take care of that? (yes, I know it's *evil*, but questioner is already using *hooks*, so we can't fall much lower ;)

Comment: OK, thanks guys. I guess I'll go with this approach after all, it seems the "nicest" way to do it. Thanks for all of your help!

Answer (score 4):

tenfour's answer is **best** in my opinion, but he/she **also** had to explain **how** to do it, not **just** to tell **what** to do, so now **I** will explain **how:**

**NOTE:** If you want the **main idea** in my solution, then you can skip to the **last step 9 much** below (begin search for it from bottom to top until you find it).

Sorry if I exaggerated with my answer and explained and detailed too much, but I promise if you will read properly, you will understand and be satisfied.

**Step 1:** Create new `WNDCLASSEX` structure, and then set its `cbSize` member to the size of this structure, in bytes, by using the `sizeof` keyword, and set `lpszClassName` member to whatever you want. Also set the hbrBackground member to the return value of **either** `GetStockObject` function to obtain **either** the black, **or** white **or** gray brush, **OR** `CreateSolidBrush` function to obtain a brush of any color you want. It is **very important** to choose the color that all your drawings do **not** use at all!!! And not just for your pleasure!

For example:

```
WNDCLASSEX wcex;
wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
wcex.lpszClassName = "myNewClassName";
HBRUSH background_brush = GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH);
wcex.hbrBackground = background_brush;
```

**Step 2:** Define a new function that is a window procedure, and then create new function pointer of it. Then set the `lpfnWndProc` member of `wcex` to that function pointer.

**Step 3:** In the new window procedure function definition, add `return 0;` which is the **last** line of code.

Above it switch uMsg parameter, and at least add the `WM_PAINT` case.
In that case, define new variable of `PAINTSTRUCT`, and call the `BeginPaint` and `EndPaint` functions. In both functions, you reference the variable like `&ps`, if `ps` is the name of the `PAINTSTRUCT` variable.

**After** you call `BeginPaint` function, add all the drawing functions you want on the target window, but make sure that the `HDC` in all drawing functions are **not** belong to the target window, but to the window which you have its handle in the **first** parameter of the window procedure, i.e. `hWnd`!!!
Call **either** `GetDC` **or** `GetWindowDC` function to retrieve hWnd's hDC **first** of all.

**NOTE:** You don't need to retrieve the target window's hDc at all!

Don't forget to add the following code line: `default: return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);` inside the block of the `switch` statement.

**Step 4:** Register the class using the `RegisterClassEx` function.

For example: `RegisterClassEx(&wcex);`

**Step 5:** In your application, create new **layered** window by using the `CreateWindowEx` function.
It is **very important** that you set the **first** parameter of this function to `WS_EX_LAYERED` to declare that the new window that you create is **layered.**

Set the **second** parameter to the name of the new registered class, for example `"myNewClassName"`, ignore the **third** parameter (set it to `NULL`), and in the **fourth** parameter, set the following flags: `WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE`

**NOTE**: `WS_POPUP` will create the new window **without** border. This is the reason I ignored the `hIcon` member of `wcex` and also the **third** parameter set to `NULL`
You can replace `WS_POPUP` with `WS_POPUPWINDOW` instead. The result will be the same, but `WS_POPUPWINDOW` also draws **outlined** gray rectangle, thin with only 1 pixel thickness all over the client area. `WS_POPUP` does **not** draw anything in contrast to `WS_POPUPWINDOW`, **just** removes the border like it.

I also set the `WS_VISIBLE` flag to show the window. If you don't set this flag, then you will have to call `ShowWindow` function after `CreateWindowEx`, in order to show the layered window.

**Step 6:** Call `SetLayeredWindowAttributes` function after `CreateWindowEx`. Set the **first** parameter to the handle of the new created layered window returned from the `CreateWindowEx` function.

Set the **second** parameter to the background color of your window's client, i.e. to the color of your solid brush stored in the `background_brush` variable of the example, which you used to set the hbrBackground member of the wcex whose type is `WNDCLASSEX`.

**Note** that the data type of this parameter is `COLORREF`, and not `HBRUSH`, i.e. it does **not** accept solid brush, but simply a color!

If you know the color of the solid brush you chose in the `GetStockObject` function, then you know how to create its `COLORREF` structure.

If you called `CreateSolidBrush` function instead, then before you call it, define new variable of `COLORREF` structure that will store the solid brush's color and the crKey in the future. Later you can use the variable in both functions: `CreateSolidBrush` and `SetLayeredWindowAttributes` (in the second parameter, i.e. `crKey`).

If you followed my example above, and you **only** have the `background_brush` variable whose type is `HBRUSH` that stores the solid brush for the hbrBackground member of wcex, and you do **not** have any proper COLORREF for the `crKey` parameter, then:

In order to obtain the color of the solid brush whose type is `HBRUSH` to `COLORREF` structure then:

> You can use GetObject function to get the LOGBRUSH information of the
>   brush, lbColor component of which will give the colour value in
>   COLORREF. You can use GetRValue, GetGValue and GetBValue functions to
>   get the individual colour components as well.

Pravin's answer to someone that had to know how to get `COLORREF` of `HBRUSH` as solid brush.

Here is the link for more information:

http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?423605-Color-of-HBRUSH

If you want another way to retrieve the proper `COLORREF` structure for the `crKey` parameter of `SetLayeredWindowAttributes` function, then you can try the `GetBkColor` function after you have retrieved the `hDc` of the new created layered window first.
**or** call `SelectObject` function instead. Set **first** parameter to the new layered window's dc, and set **second** parameter to the `hbrBackground` member of wcex or `bakcground_brush` of the example above.

Then just call the `GetDCBrushColor` function to get the `COLORREF` structure for the `crKey` parameter of the `SetLayeredWindowAttributes` function.

Ignore the **third** parameter (set `bAlpha` to `NULL`), and in the **fourth** parameter set only the `LWA_COLORKEY` flag.
crKey is the color of hbrBackground, the entire client of the layered window won't be drawn, except other pixels that their color is not `crKey`.
Now all what you have to do is to bound the layered window on the target window's client.

**Step 7:** Call **either** `FindWindow` **or** `FindWindowEx` function to retrieve the handle of the target window, if you don't have it yet.

**Step 8:** Write the message loop (or select and copy the piece of code below and paste it to yours):

```
MSG msg;
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

**Step 9 (last):** In the message loop (inside the block of the while loop) no matter where (before TranslateMessage or after DispatchMessage or between them), write another piece of code that will **every moment** bound the layered window to the target window's client:

First of all **create** new POINT structure, and set its coordinates to (0; 0)
(Set its `x` and `y` members to 0).

Then call `ClientToScreen` function. Set the **first** parameter to the handle of the target window (returned from the `FindWindow` or `FindWindowEx` function), and in the **second** parameter reference the POINT structure, which you created before.

After the call to `ClientToScreen` function, your POINT structure stores the coordinates of the most LEFT TOP edge of the target window (in screen coordinates, measured in pixels unit).

Now you have to retrieve the **size** of the target window's client. To do so next **define** new variable whose type is the `RECT` structure.

Then call `GetClientRect` function. Set the **first** parameter to the handle of the target window, and in the **second** parameter reference the variable whose type is the `RECT` structure.

After the call to `GetClientRect` function, the `RECT` variable stores the width and the height of the target window's client, measured in pixels unit. The `right` member stores the **width**, and the `bottom` member stores the **height**. Ignore the `left` and `top`
members of the variable whose type is the `RECT` structure. They are not used and not set, and always will have their default value, i.e. 0 only in this case.

After you have the position of the target window's client (the location and the size), now you can bound your layered window to the target window's client by calling **either** `MoveWindow` **or** `SetWindowPos` function, like this:

```
MoveWindow(hWnd, point.x, point.y, rect.right, rect.bottom, TRUE);
//If you want, you can set the last parameter to FALSE.
//OR
SetWindowPos(hWnd, hTargetWnd, point.x, point.y, rect.right, rect.bottom, NULL);
//If you want, you can specify some flags in the last parameter.
//Where hWnd is the handle of the layered window returned from CreateWindowEx function, and hTargetWnd is the handle of the target window returned from either FindWindow or FindWindowEx function.
```

If you decided to use the `MoveWindow` function, and you have problem that you don't see your paintings on the target window, that is because the layered window is **below** the target window. You will have to change the call to `SetWindowPos` function instead to solve this problem then.
In the second parameter I invoked the system that I want to place the bounded layered window **above** the target window. If it still doesn't work, you can change this parameter and set it to **either** `HWND_TOP` **or** `HWND_TOPMOST` flag.

I am sure after that it should work fine.
Don't forget sometimes to invalidate or redraw or update the layered window to update your drawings on the target window. You can call **either** `InvalidateRect` **or** `RedrawWindow` **or** `UpdateWindow` function to do that.

For example:

```
POINT point;
ClientToScreen(hTargetWnd, &point);

RECT rect;
GetClientRect(hTargetWnd, &rect);

MoveWindow(hWnd, point.x, point.y, rect.right, rect.bottom, TRUE);
//OR
SetWindowPos(hWnd, hTargetWnd, point.x, point.y, rect.right, rect.bottom, NULL);

InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
//If you want, you can set the third parameter to FALSE.
```

(You can select and copy the example code above and paste it to yours too):

The example code can be in the message loop, it means that the layered window will be bound and updated **every moment**, but if you do **not** want every moment, but everytime you do something, or everytime something is happening, with the target window, which not belongs to your application, like Notepad, then you'll have to make call to the `SetWindowsHookEx` function. You can get more information about that function on MSDN site and other sites on the web.

If you want that to be happen every moment, but not in the message loop, then you can do it in other while loop of other thread, but you will have make a function for it and call `CreateThread` function. Again, you can also get information about that function on MSDN site and other sites on the web

Make sure that the while loop of the thread ends when the process of your application is **either** exited **or** terminated.

You can also try either `IsWindow` or `IsWindowVisible` function in the while loop condition to determine to stop when the layered window or/and the target window is/are being **either** destroyed **or** closed (finished, not going to be minimized or iconic).

Comment: This is complex, do you have any simpler way to do it in C# or a complete code example? I want to make my UI such that it will completely cover target application (an applock UI). Thanks for all this

Answer (score 2):

No.

Instead, why not hook `WM_PAINT`, so you draw when they draw?

Comment: I thought that a program can draw the window without sending the message WM_PAINT, through GetDC or GetWindowDC. I thought that WM_PAINT gets sent only when BeginPaint is used; am I wrong?

Comment: @Ani, that's the other way around: you need to call the `BeginPaint()`/`EndPaint()` pair of functions from your `WM_PAINT` handler in order to acquire a properly clipped DC and to mark the updated region as valid.

Answer (score 2):

You can try sending [WM_SETREDRAW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145219%28VS.85%29.aspx) messages to the window, with `wParam` set to `FALSE` to suspend painting, then set to `TRUE` to restore normal behavior.

That's quite an intrusive solution, though.

Comment: You can also send EM_SETEVENTMASK to suspend event messages. But be sure to turn it back on by restoring the previous Event mask. I agree that this is a pretty intrusive solution.

Comment: @theChrisKent, [EM_SETEVENTMASK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774238%28VS.85%29.aspx) only applies to [rich edit controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774366%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) (note the `EM_` prefix). I think questioner wants to draw over top-level windows.

Comment: Why is it intrusive? And am I guaranteed that all applications will respond to this message? I have never seen this message before in examples I've seen, so will DefWindowProc process this message if the application itself doesn't?

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi, Good point.  I was looking at old code that did exactly that (suspend refresh on a rich edit control).

Comment: @Ani, that's intrusive because you would be sending a intimate message to some window you don't even know, and "stop drawing yourself" is quite harsh as an introduction. `WM_SETREDRAW` sets a system flag: if the target window doesn't ignore that message in its procedure (i.e. passes it to DefWindowProc()), it might not even realize it can't update itself anymore, and bad things may happen.

Comment: I see, thanks. I would like to be a less intrusive as possible, and this seems to be a little too drastic for my program.

Comment: @Ani, then I'd go with @tenfour's answer and create a overlapped, transparent window of your own, so you can draw over any window without putting hooks all over the place :)