# Adding an overlay to the active window

Tags: c#, .net

[image]

I am trying to figure out if there is a way in C# to add such an overlay to another window's Title bar. I am trying to make a program that monitors your keyboard input and will show prompts based if a certain word is typed. I already have everything else working, but this.

Comment: Yes, but its not easy. It would involve writing a DLL hook for getting notified when a window is created, removed, activated, repositioned or resized. Read [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18638/Using-Window-Messages-to-Implement-Global-System-H) on how to create system-wide hooks in C#. Your hook would have to override the WM_PAINT event.

Comment: Another useful article about C# and Windows hooks: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/calvin_hsia/2016/11/30/its-easy-to-use-windows-hooks-even-from-c/

Answer (score 0):

One way is to hook into the global Message Procedure with SetWindowsHookEx(WH_GETMESSAGE, ..., NULL) then in GetMsgProc() you check for WM_PAINT messages, and if the HWND is the currently top window, comparing message->hwnd with result of GetTopWindow(NULL), after that you can add your custom GDI Drawing code.

Detailed example of the Hooking DLL code can be found in the answer for this Question
[How to draw graphics/text on top of another application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815667/how-to-draw-graphics-text-on-top-of-another-application)