# g.Draw blinking a lot

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using this function in a Timer:

```cs
IntPtr Handle = FindWindow(null, "Notepad");

if (radioButton1.Checked)
{
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(Handle))
    {
        Pen PN = new Pen(pictureBox2.BackColor, (Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown2.Value)));
        g.DrawLine(PN, 961, 520, 961, 560);
        g.DrawLine(PN, 985, 540, 935, 540);
        g.Dispose();
    }
}
```

But the draw is blinking alot even if i set the timer interval to 1

Comment: _even if i set the timer interval to 1_ Huh? Meaning _even if I run it as often as I can_ ??? (Interval is in ms !)

Comment: @TaW Yeh.. got any solution ?

Comment: For a slower blink rate set Interval to larger value. 1000 is one second. - Also don't dispose what is created in a using clause!

Comment: @TaW Slower interval is actually even worse
It's not even drawing it properly

Comment: Not sure if your approach will work. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815667/how-to-draw-graphics-text-on-top-of-another-application)

Comment: What is that you actually want to do here? I doubt you just want to paint a cross in a fixed position over Notepad's client area.

Answer (score -1):

Your code will only get the main window's handle.

Most applications have other controls that cover that clientarea.

Instead of drawing onto the clientarea you need to get the the handle of Notepad's textarea.

You can test this by

- testing the handle value. If it is `0` you only got the desktop. This probably what you have been seeing.
- If you test it with a form of your own it will  show your cross if and only if the drawing area is not covered by other controls..

It is also a good idea to enumerate the processes to get at the correct titles. Here is an example I found in another post:

```
public static IntPtr WinGetHandle(string wName)
{
    IntPtr hWnd = IntPtr.Zero;
    foreach (Process pList in Process.GetProcesses())
    {
        if (pList.MainWindowTitle.Contains(wName))
        {
            hWnd = pList.MainWindowHandle;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(pList.MainWindowTitle);
    }
    return hWnd;
}
```

It will take some more trial and error code to find a suitable subhandle of the application's surface..

Comment: Still can't figure out how to fix the blinking draw
it's working better when i use "for ( ; ; )", but if i use that i can't go back to the form anymore

Comment: What rate do you aim to get? Also: Are you claiming that your code actually draws onto Notepad?? (Test: Move Notepade around; will it still get the cross at the same spot??)